# Using ffmpeg static libraries in an visual studio explress C++ 2010 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg, linker

As the title says, I have been trying to get ffmpeg/libav libraries to work in MSVC++ 2010. 
However, I keep running in the following error while coding on debug mode.

code:

```
extern "C" 
{
    #ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
    #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
    #endif
    #include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat\avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale\swscale.h>
    #include <libavutil\avutil.h>
}
int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

console:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ffmpeg, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ffmpeg.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _av_register_all referenced in       function _main
1>C:\Users\okki\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ffmpeg\Debug\ffmpeg.exe : fatal    error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I used [zeranoe's](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) latest build git-56ba331 (2013-05-14).

And I have tried the following to fix this:

- configuring the project to look for both the x64 and x86 libraries.
- Add the DLLs from the 'shared' package to both library folders.
- Add the library directory to both the linker options and VC++ Directories.

I have been stuck on this for a while, and any suggestion can help. 
If any extra info is needed I will happily provide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download latest files from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/shared/ and from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/dev/ (Shared and Dev) and unpacked them into `ffmpeg\shared` and `ffmpeg\dev` respectively

Create a new console project, set the value of "Additional Include Directory" to `ffmpeg\dev\include`, "Additional Library Directories" to `ffmpeg\dev\lib\`

Add to your code

```
# pragma comment (lib, "avformat.lib")
```

(In real projects you will need at least the files `avutil.lib`, `avcodec.lib`)

To run the program, copy the `*.dll` files from the `ffmpeg\shared\bin` to output folder

Comment: Oh wow it actually linked this time. Seemed to be missing the #pragma comment. 

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you please post some sample code, because I used your example and it wont run?