# Linker error using FFMPEG with Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-c++, linker, ffmpeg, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to write a program using FFMPEG libraries. I read about in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586437/using-ffmpeg-static-libraries-in-an-visual-studio-explress-c-2010-project%20%22%22) link. I downloaded Shared and Devs files from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/.

I created a console project and this is the configuration:

**Additional Libraries Directories**
[image]

**Additional Include Directories**
[image]

And here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment (lib, "avformat.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "avcodec.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "avutil.lib")

extern "C"
{
    #ifndef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
    #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
    #endif
    #include <libavcodec\avcodec.h>
    #include <libavformat\avformat.h>
    #include <libswscale\swscale.h>
    #include <libavutil\avutil.h>
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

And the error I am getting is this:

> Error 1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _av_register_all
> referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\Andres\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\PruebaFFMPEG\PruebaFFMPEG\PruebaFFMPEG.obj  PruebaFFMPEG
>
> Error 2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved
> externals C:\Users\Andres\Documents\Visual Studio
> 2013\Projects\PruebaFFMPEG\Debug\PruebaFFMPEG.exe PruebaFFMPEG

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to link a 32-bit application with 64-bit libraries. Download 32-bit libraries from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ or create x64 configuration for your solution.

Comment: I downloaded 64bit version because I have a 64bit Windows, will 32bit work? How is x64 configuration?

Comment: Open Project properties -> click Configuration Manager... -> Active Solution Platform -> New.. -> Select x64 (see screenshot http://goo.gl/54ND5t)